# Best approach to detect change on react page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am developing react hook components which uses material-ui controls for inputs. I have been googling and haven't been able to find a good example of this. What I am trying to do is show a popup message to user if he made any changes to an input field/checkbox/radio-button etc and try to navigate away/close the browser tab, without saving the information.
I have seen people talking about "the page is dirty if setstate" has been called. Is that the best solution or there are smarter ways to determine if information has been changed on the page.

Comment: show some code. so we know what u have tried

Comment: I'm building a web app with the same functionality and I'm wondering if you found any "solution" to this? I feel like putting a OnChange on every text input will be quite demanding for just observing 1 change.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code this is a bit challenging topic to guide. But you can add `onChange` event listeners to input fields, checkboxes and radio buttons. onChange is called every time user clicks or writes with the elements.

In the onchange handler you can set state which contains all changes user has made.

Comment: I know that is an option at control level. So this is a under construction application that will have hundreds of pages with thousands of controls . So I was wondering if there is any smarter approach that would require less coding, avoid writing code in onchange event of every control.